# Could I go to another country to get vaccinated for COVID-19 in time for an event?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, health, vaccinations

I've got an event in the US that I'm going to, the only problem is that I would need to be vaccinated for COVID-19.

This raises a problem as I live in the UK and I'm under 18, so the vaccine isn't offered for us here.

The only solution I could think of is travelling to another country that does offer the vaccine to teenagers. The problem here is, where? And would that be possible?
I was thinking that if I could find a country in Europe that offers that, it might make things a bit easier.

I would need to be vaccinated before July, which I now realise while typing, is probably a really slim chance.

Comment: An event in the US you’re going to in July? You are aware that unless you are a US citizen or permanent resident or are part of the small number of exempted aliens, you are currently not allowed into the US if you have been in the UK, Ireland or the Schengen Area in the last 14 days? Also, how old are you? The cut-off is not the same for all vaccines and in all countries.

Comment: I'm 16, but I guess I haven't got the chance then...

Comment: So apparently travel to the US opens up on July 7th. The event is on July 15th...

Comment: Do you have any source for this? I’m not aware of any decision on that topic yet and a very quick Google search did not reveal anything on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Given that vaccination takes 2 shots, given 6-8 weeks apart typically, you're already out of time.
Exception is the Janssen/Johnson & Johnson vaccine but that's not been widely approved.

And then there's the problem of finding a country that will a) let you in without being vaccinated and b) offers their vaccines to foreigners who aren't residents. Very slim chance again.

And all that assuming you had the funds to pay for a) the travel to and from that country, b) the probable mandatory quarantine there upon arrival, c) the vaccine itself.

And after that you'd still be required to be in mandatory quarantine most likely upon your return home.

So no, it's highly unlikely you'll be able to get your vaccine somewhere else. All you can hope for is getting yourself on a priority list with the NHS somehow (and really, that requires medical conditions you don't want at your age).

Comment: In many countries the Janssen vaccine is not recommended (or not allowed at all) for young people (the cut-off is usually at 60 or 65 years old), because, like the AstraZeneca vaccine, the (very low) risk is actually higher than that linked to COVID. So only Pfizer or Moderna are on the table, and very few countries allow under-18s to get any of those. Also, one is considered fully vaccinated only 3 weeks after the last shot. Impossible for July.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess I won't be going to that event then :/ oh, well. It was worth a try. Thanks for the information, anyways.

Comment: @jcaron In the US at least, one is considered fully vaccinated 2 weeks after the second dose of Pfizer/Moderna, not 3 weeks after.  So technically it would be possible to be fully vaccinated with Pfizer (3 weeks between doses) by the 17th of July - but it would be incredibly tight (first dose no later than the 12th of June).

Comment: @jcaron I included it mostly to be complete. If I hadn't someone'd inevitably have claimed that it needs only a single shot :)